# Uploading and handling .csv file to an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, backend

I'm relatively new to the backend/C# programming but I have a task to deal with it.

I have created a simple CRUD operation for managing books using the ASP.NET Core Web API.

Here's my task:

I need to upload a `.csv` or Excel related files to an endpoint, validate the file extension and populate the database with the data in the file.

The `POST` endpoint that I've created does add a new book, but only one at a time. So generally what I'm trying to do here is creating an endpoint for adding multiple books at once using the data in the `.csv` file.

Any kind of hint or help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain a library that might help you with this: [Sylvan.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Csv](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.AspNetCore/blob/main/docs/CsvFormatter.md).

It implements an AspNET formatter for CSV. If you already have an API endpoint that handles a single item, this can make it very easy to add support for loading multiple.

Assuming you have an existing API:

```
class Book {
  public string Author { get;set;}
  public DateTime PublishDate {get;set;}
  public string ISBN {get;set;}
  // ...
}

class LibraryController {
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task AddBook(Book book) 
  {
    // your existing book insert code

  }
}
```

After adding the CSV formatter you can add a new endpoint as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task AddBooks(IEnumerable<Book> books) {

  foreach(var book in books) {
    await AddBook(book);
  }
}
```

The package takes care of parsing the incoming CSV data and binding it to Book. This allows a client to optionally send JSON or CSV, determined by the `Content-Type` request header.

If the data file is expected to be very large, it would be more efficient to load the CSV data into the database with a `SqlBulkCopy` (or the equivalent for your database system), but you probably shouldn't worry about that unless you run into performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload multiple files using IFormCollection. Examples can be found here- https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/IFormCollection/-/php-iformcollection-class-examples.html
Then you can read the csv into your class using csvHelper nuget(https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) and save the objects to database. examples are here- https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/

IFormFile for single file, IFormCollection for multiple files

Comment: If I need to upload a single .csv file should I use IFormFile or IFormCollection?

Comment: IFormFile for single file, IFormCollection for multiple files. You need to send array of files as formdata from website for IFormCollection , you can also send single file array also. Here is example to send file using axios- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/axios+file+upload